# version conflict firebase libraries

Tags: android, firebase

I am getting this error:

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the
>   google-services plugin (information about the latest version is
>   available at
>   https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)
>   or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 16.0.1.

I think the error I am getting is due to implementing `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0` because if I remove it, building is successful. But on trying version 16.0.1 of `com.google.android.gms` for messaging, I get this message:

> Unable to resolve error

I think the error means that `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:16.0.1` is unavailable. How can my problem be solved ?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.anamika.anamika"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.9.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Try    `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0` it works in my case

Comment: Have you tried upgrading the other versions rather than downgrading one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check this out](https://medium.com/@suchydan/how-to-solve-google-play-services-version-collision-in-gradle-dependencies-ef086ae5c75f)

> You need to search over your native dependecies in node_modules for their build.gradle and in this files look for dependecies starting with com.google.android.gms or com.google.firebase. After that you need to exclude these internal dependecies and force use of same version everywhere.

Answer (score 9):

in Android studio there are 2 buld gradle file.

1. build.gradle (Project: ProjectName)
2. build.gradle (Module: App)

I failed to upgrade `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0` too and then I edit `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.1'` to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'`in **build.gradle (Project: ProjectName)** and it works. i can finally upgrade to `17.1.0`.